# Nullability of argument doesn't match constraint type

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I've written the following extension method:

```
public static void NotifyChanged<T>(this INotifyPropertyChanged inpc, ref T current, T newValue, Action<PropertyChangedEventArgs> eventRaiser, [CallerMemberName] string? name = null) where T : IEquatable<T> {
    if (current.Equals(newValue)) { return; }
    current = newValue;
    eventRaiser(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
```

that can be used like this:

```
public class Foo : Bar, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    private string? rootExpression;

    public string? RootExpression {
        get => rootExpression;
        set => this.NotifyChanged(ref rootExpression, value, args => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args));
    }
}
```

This saves much of the boilerplate of writing INPC-aware properties.

However, I now get a compiler warning error at the call to `NotifyChanged`:

> The type 'string?' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'INotifyPropertyChangedExtensions.NotifyChanged(INotifyPropertyChanged, ref T, T, Action, string?)'. Nullability of type argument 'string?' doesn't match constraint type 'System.IEquatable'.

AFAICT the error is saying that `string?` cannot be cast to `IEquatable<string?>`, only `string` can be cast to `IEquatable<string>`.

How can I resolve this? Apply some attribute? Or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
where T : IEquatable<T>
```

This says that `T` must be a non-nullable `IEquatable<T>`. You want it to be nullable. You can say this by adding a `?`:

```
where T : IEquatable<T>?
```

Note that this will then complain on `if (current.Equals(newValue))`, which will throw if `current` is `null`.

---

The normal way to do this is not by constraining `T` to be an `IEquatable<T>`, but to use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`. If `T` implements `IEquatable<T>`, this gives you an equality comparer which calls `IEquatable<T>.Equals`, otherwise it falls back to calling the normal `object.Equals`.

This also solves your issue of an NRE if `current` is `null`:

```
public static void NotifyChanged<T>(
    this INotifyPropertyChanged inpc,
    ref T current, T newValue,
    Action<PropertyChangedEventArgs> eventRaiser,
    [CallerMemberName] string? name = null)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(current, newValue)) { return; }
    current = newValue;
    eventRaiser(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
```

---

It's also rare to pass in `eventRaiser`: normally you'd make `NotifyChanged` a method on a base class which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, rather than making it an extension method. Then you can just let `NotifyChanged` raise the `PropertyChanged` event itself, or you write another method such as `OnPropertyChanged` which raises `PropertyChanged` and call that from `NotifyChanged`.

If you do want to pass in the event to raise, you could just pass in the `PropertyChangedEventHandler`:

```
public static void NotifyChanged<T>(
    this INotifyPropertyChanged _,
    ref T current, T newValue,
    PropertyChangedEventHandler eventHandler,
    [CallerMemberName] string? name = null)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(current, newValue)) { return; }
    current = newValue;
    eventHandler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}

this.NotifyChanged(ref rootExpression, value, PropertyChanged);
```

Comment: I can't let `NotifyChanged` raise the event, because it's an extension method; a class's events can only be raised within that class.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the boilerplate of checking equality and raising the event for each property. Ideally, I would inherit from an INPC-implementing base class with a `NotifyChanged` method as you suggested; but I can't do that in this case: I have to inherit from a specific class which I cannot modify.

Comment: @ZevSpitz In which case, that specific bit at the end doesn't apply to you. The first two sections do, however

Comment: But I do like your suggestion of passing in the handler instead of a delegate.

Comment: also works with: `where T : class?`